# How to start an activity from a button click

Tags: android

Can you help me with code please?
I have 4 activities : Activity1 Activity2 Activity3 and Activity4
and in Main Menu I have 4 buttons : button1 button2 button3 and button4.

goal:

- When I click on button1 - activity1 starts.
- When I click on button2 - activity2 starts.
- When I click on button3 - activity3 starts.
- When I click on button4 - activity4 starts.

Can anyone help me with code please? It's hard for me :|

Comment: nothing :( i dont know anything about java :|

Comment: Well, I'd suggest you start by learning some basic Java skills before you start trying to write Android applications. There are plenty of tutorials on Java and Android, so start there.

Comment: my english is not wery well . maybe not so hard with java than with english .)

Comment: Please go through Android basics before doing any code.http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html will help

Answer (score 3):

To start a new Activity in Android use..

```
Intent activity1 = new Intent(YourClass.this, Your_class_you_want_to_start.java);
startActivity(activity1);
```

Do the same thing for the rest of your buttons but change the Intents name and change the starting class to the corresponding one.

Also i would recommend you grabbing a Book on Androi Development or maybe even Java if you arent familiar with it. This is how i started, so it just takes some patience and hard work. Check out [Commonsware](http://commonsware.com/)  best place to start.

Comment: I appreciate best way of doing !

Answer (score 1):

Do the following while you are in an Activity to start another Activity by using it's intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), Activity.class);
this.startActivity(intent, 0);
```

You can also make it a one-liner. Don't forget to check out: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html for more information about Android activities.

To use a button in Android, read the following page, it is quite self-explanitory: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html about using buttons. But to sum it up, you'll have to override the OnClick in a button class.